# Name aesthetics using ".resid" syntax in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Someone pointed out to me that there's a different way to specify the `data` and the `aesthetics` in `ggplot2` as below. I've never seen this -- in all the books, docs, `data` is always a data frame and inside `aes` are the names of the variables. What's this dot syntax?

```
y <- rnorm(100) ; x <- rnorm(100) 
m <- lm(y ~ x)

library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(data = m, aes(.resid, .fitted)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Have a look at `fortify(m)` . The dot isnt doing anything clever, it is included as part of the names that `fortify` produces. So the magic lief in the fortify function.

Comment: @user20650 very to-the-point answer. Thanks! If you post the comment as an answer, I'll be happy to check it. Also, could you discuss how `fortify` is used in ggplot? Or how do I look into the source code of ggplot?

Comment: Have a look at `?fortify` which will lead to `fortify.lm`. As for the code use `methods` to look for available ggplot methods and then attach the namespace to look at the code. eg `methods(ggplot)` then pick one to look at  `ggplot2:::ggplot.default`

Comment: Comments and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310728/most-succinct-way-to-label-annotate-extreme-values-with-ggplot/10312520#10312520) might be useful.

Comment: @Sandy, good memory... there is always an answer on SO if you know where to look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade comment

`ggplot` is calling `fortify` on the `lm` object, which produces a dataframe that is then passed to `ggplot.data.frame`.

To see the code use

```
ggplot2:::ggplot.default

#function (data = NULL, mapping = aes(), ..., environment = parent.frame()) 
#{
#    ggplot.data.frame(fortify(data, ...), mapping, environment = environment)
#}
#<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

As for `fortify` it coerces various models and R objects to dataframes. Have a look at `methods(fortify)`.

You can directly see the results of `fortify`

```
ff <- fortify(m)
names(ff)
#[1] "y"   "x"    ".hat"   ".sigma"    ".cooksd"   ".fitted"   ".resid"  ".stdresid"
```

So the dot isn't doing anything clever within `aes`, but is actually part of the column names that fortify produces.